# Gathering data using R - multiple urls

Tags: r, xml, loops, web-scraping

I have a dataframe which has a several columns and rows - some contain information, some are filled with NA, which should be replaced with certain data.

The rows represent specific instruments and columns contain various details of the instrument in a given row. The last column of the dataframe has a url for each instrument, which then will be used to grab data for empty columns:

```
 Issuer  NIN or ISIN           Type Nominal Value # of Bonds Issue Volume Start Date End Date
1 NBRK KZW1KD079112 discount notes            NA         NA           NA         NA       NA
2 NBRK KZW1KD079146 discount notes            NA         NA           NA         NA       NA
3 NBRK KZW1KD079153 discount notes            NA         NA           NA         NA       NA
4 NBRK KZW1KD089137 discount notes            NA         NA           NA         NA       NA

 URL
1 http://www.kase.kz/en/gsecs/show/NTK007_1911
2 http://www.kase.kz/en/gsecs/show/NTK007_1914
3 http://www.kase.kz/en/gsecs/show/NTK007_1915
4 http://www.kase.kz/en/gsecs/show/NTK008_1913
```

For example, with the following code I get the details for the first instrument in the row `NBRK KZW1KD079112`:

```
sp = readHTMLTable(newd$URL[[1]])
sp[[4]]
```

Which gives the following:

```
                                            V1                                                              

    V2
1                                     Trading code                                                         NTK007_1911
2                               List of securities                                                            official
3                              System of quotation                                                               price
4                                Unit of quotation                                   nominal value percentage fraction
5                               Quotation currency                                                                 KZT
6                               Quotation accuracy                                                        4 characters
7                       Trade lists admission date                                                            04/21/17
8                               Trade opening date                                                            04/24/17
9                       Trade lists exclusion date                                                            04/28/17
10                                        Security                                                                <NA>
11                                     Bond's name short-term notes of the National Bank of the Republic of Kazakhstan
12                                            NSIN                                                        KZW1KD079112
13                   Currency of issue and service                                                                 KZT
14               Nominal value in issue's currency                                                              100.00
15                      Number of registered bonds                                                       1,929,319,196
16                     Number of bonds outstanding                                                       1,929,319,196
17                               Issue volume, KZT                                                     192,931,919,600
18 Settlement basis (days in month / days in year)                                                        actual / 365
19                       Date of circulation start                                                            04/21/17
20                          Circulation term, days                                                                   7
21              Register fixation date at maturity                                                            04/27/17
22                        Principal repayment date                                                            04/28/17
23                                    Paying agent                          Central securities depository JSC (Almaty)
24                                       Registrar                          Central securities depository JSC (Almaty)
```

From this, I will have to keep only:

```
14               Nominal value in issue's currency                                                              100.00
16                     Number of bonds outstanding                                                       1,929,319,196
17                               Issue volume, KZT                                                     192,931,919,600
19                       Date of circulation start                                                            04/21/17
22                        Principal repayment date                                                            04/28/17
```

I then will copy the needed data to the initial dataframe and carry on with the next row ... The dataframe consist of 100+ rows and will keep changing.

I would appreciate any help.

**UPDATE:**

Looks like the data that I need are not always in `sp[[4]]`. Sometimes its `sp[[7]]`, maybe in the future it will be totally different table. Is there any way that looks for the information in the scraped tables and identifies a specific table that could be used further to collect data?:

```
sp = readHTMLTable(newd$URL[[1]])
sp[[4]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(XML)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

name = c(
"NBRK KZW1KD079112 discount notes",                                           
"NBRK KZW1KD079146 discount notes",                                        
"NBRK KZW1KD079153 discount notes",                                         
"NBRK KZW1KD089137 discount notes")                                           

URL = c(
"http://www.kase.kz/en/gsecs/show/NTK007_1911",
"http://www.kase.kz/en/gsecs/show/NTK007_1914",
"http://www.kase.kz/en/gsecs/show/NTK007_1915",
"http://www.kase.kz/en/gsecs/show/NTK008_1913")

# data
instruments <- data.frame(name, URL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# define the columns wanted and the mapping to desired name
# extend to all wanted columns
wanted <- c("Nominal value in issue's currency" = "Nominal Value",
            "Number of bonds outstanding" = "# of Bonds Issue")

# function returns a data frame of wanted columns for given URL
getValues <- function (name, url) {
  # get the table and rename columns
  sp = readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df <- sp[[4]]
  names(df) <- c("full_name", "value")

  # filter and remap wanted columns
  result <- df[df$full_name %in% names(wanted),]
  result$column_name <- sapply(result$full_name, function(x) {wanted[[x]]})

  # add the identifier to every row
  result$name <- name
  return (result[,c("name", "column_name", "value")])
}

# invoke function for each name/URL pair - returns list of data frames
columns <- apply(instruments[,c("name", "URL")], 1, function(x) {getValues(x[["name"]], x[["URL"]])})

# bind using dplyr:bind_rows to make a tall data frame
tall <- bind_rows(columns)

# make wide using dcast from reshape2
wide <- dcast(tall, name ~ column_name, id.vars = "value")

wide

#                               name # of Bonds Issue Nominal Value
# 1 NBRK KZW1KD079112 discount notes    1,929,319,196        100.00
# 2 NBRK KZW1KD079146 discount notes    1,575,000,000        100.00
# 3 NBRK KZW1KD079153 discount notes      701,390,693        100.00
# 4 NBRK KZW1KD089137 discount notes    1,380,368,000        100.00

    enter code here
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code is working, but when I try to run it for for all instruments, I am getting the following error:  `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "name", value = "KZW1KD919127") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0 ` 

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Hmmm ... I just finished inspecting this specific instrument, and figured that the data that I need is contained not in `sp[[4]]` but `sp[[7]]`. Is it somehow possible to incorporate this condition in there?

Comment: The not so nice hack is something like `df <- if_else(name == "foo", sp[[4]], sp[[7]])`. I generally prefer the `dplyr if_else` rather than the base `ifelse` because it preserves class. Better approach is to learn to use `library(rvest)` because it supports CSS selectors in the `html_nodes` function which can target the 'id' attributes in the html instead of position

Comment: Yeah, well ... xml seemed more straightforward-ish as I don't know CSS. SelectorGadget is not helping much with `rvest`. Thanks anyway. Will investigate further.

Comment: Now using `rvest` I modified this bit: `getValues <- function (name, url) {
 df <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
 html_nodes("table.top") %>%
 html_table()
 df = as.data.frame(df)
 names(df) <- c("full_name", "value")` Thanks a lot again!