# For loop with readHTMLTable from XML package

Tags: r, xml, for-loop

I am trying to use `for` loop to extract data from multiple URLs. The problem is, the data I need found in different tables. The original question I had is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654797/gathering-data-using-r-multiple-urls). Initial data I have:

```
 Code Issuer         ISIN           Type                                          URL
1 NTK007_1915   NBRK KZW1KD079153 discount notes http://www.kase.kz/en/gsecs/show/NTK007_1915
2 NTK007_1917   NBRK KZW1KD079179 discount notes http://www.kase.kz/en/gsecs/show/NTK007_1917
3 NTK007_1918   NBRK KZW1KD079187 discount notes http://www.kase.kz/en/gsecs/show/NTK007_1918
4 NTK028_1896   NBRK KZW1KD288960 discount notes http://www.kase.kz/en/gsecs/show/NTK028_1896
5 NTK028_1903   NBRK KZW1KD289034 discount notes http://www.kase.kz/en/gsecs/show/NTK028_1903
6 NTK028_1909   NBRK KZW1KD289091 discount notes http://www.kase.kz/en/gsecs/show/NTK028_1909
```

And I have been trying this code:

```
wanted <- c("Nominal value in issue's currency" = "Nominal Value",
            "Number of bonds outstanding" = "# of Bonds Issue")

# function returns a data frame of wanted columns for given URL
getValues1 <- function (name, url) {
  # get the table and rename columns
  sp = readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df <- sp[[4]]
  names(df) <- c("full_name", "value")

  # filter and remap wanted columns
  result <- df[df$full_name %in% names(wanted),]
  result$column_name <- sapply(result$full_name, function(x) {wanted[[x]]})

  # add the identifier to every row
  result$name <- name
  return (result[,c("name", "column_name", "value")])
}

getValues2 <- function (name, url) {
  # get the table and rename columns
  sp = readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df <- sp[[7]]
  names(df) <- c("full_name", "value")

  # filter and remap wanted columns
  result <- df[df$full_name %in% names(wanted),]
  result$column_name <- sapply(result$full_name, function(x) {wanted[[x]]})

  # add the identifier to every row
  result$name <- name
  return (result[,c("name", "column_name", "value")])
}

# invoke function for each name/URL pair - returns list of data frames
for (i in 1:length(newd$URL)) {
    sp = readHTMLTable(newd$URL[[i]])
    if (dim(sp[[4]])[[2]] = 2) {
        columns = getValues1(x[["name"]], x[["URL"]])
    } else {
        columns = getValues2(x[["name"]], x[["URL"]])
    }
print (columns)
}
```

So, basically I am looking at the number of columns of a table and if it is not equal to 2, then get the data from another table. So far R is giving the following error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readHTMLTable’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
```

Please help.

Comment: It's a much better idea to use CSS or XPath selectors to deliberately select the table(s) you want. Otherwise, you have to resort to control flow gymnastics, and you still have a good chance of accidentally pulling something you don't want. Also, changing the `for` loop to `lapply` will more naturally give you a tidy list.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could take a look at these two pages: 
http://www.kase.kz/en/gsecs/show/NTK007_1915
http://www.kase.kz/en/gsecs/show/NTK091_1912

I want to get the data under "Characteristics" label. What would be the CSS and/or XPath code for these two pages? 

Still struggling with selectorgadget ...

Comment: ahh, I think I got it finally:  `html_nodes("#main > div.rigid > div.float-wrapper-rigid > div > table.content-table.top") %>%
  html_table()`

Comment: You could just use `h %>% html_node('table.top') %>% html_table()` where `h` is the parsed page. It can't handle the header row in the middle, though, so you'll have to split it afterwards.